# Exporting DataGridView data into a new excel file - How to include column names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying this but nothing get Column name or header in excel.

```
for (i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
     xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].Name;
}

for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
    {
         DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView2[j, i];
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HeaderText instead of the ColumnName. This should give you the text which is displayed on the DataGridView.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
```

Comment: thanks Marius but by HeaderText its also not working and not display column names